# In TypeScript what is the idiomatic way to filter an array of strings with a regular expression AND map to capturing groups?

Tags: typescript, eslint

My input input is an array of strings `lines`.  I would like to write code like the following in TypeScript.

```
lines
  .filter((line:string) => line.match(/resource "[^"]+"/))
  .map((line:string) => line.match(/resource "([^"]+"/)[1])
```

Frankly, I'm a little lost on how to accomplish this in TypeScript, and these are some of the reasons.

1. I know that at runtime the second `match` won't be `null` and will have captured something into slot `[1]`, but the TypeScript compiler can't seem to figure this out and nags me.
2. I'm able to work around it with a second `map` operation that uses a ternary operator `?` to check for null or empty arrays, and that actually compiles and runs fine.  But the, the linter complains in a Git pre-commit hook, which tells me I'm on the wrong track.

What *is* the right track?  What is the "correct" way to do this in TypeScript?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match all the strings first, using optional chaining for brevity, then filter later by whether there was a match or not.

```
const matches = lines
    .map(line => line.match(/resource "([^"]+")/)?.[1])
    .filter(Boolean) as string[];
```

But your matching of `/resource "([^"]+"/` looks a bit suspicious - did you really want to exclude the first `"` and include the second? Or might you have wanted `/resource "([^"]+)"/`?

Comment: Thanks, no I was typing the regexp cold so it had a typo.  But, that's irrelevant to the question, which was more about TypeScript, types, chaining, checking for nulls.  What I didn't know about was
1. conditional chaining with ?.
2. what filter(Boolean) is doing.  What IS it doing?

Comment: Anyway, you're pretty close.  Your posted answer didn't actually work for me because the linter complained about line being of any type.  But it was a simple fix:

    const matches = lines
      .map((line:string) => line.match(/resource "([^"]+)"/)?.[1])
      .filter(Boolean) as string[];

Comment: You should type your `lines` properly wherever it's defined - do something like `const lines = ['a', 'b']` or something like that so TypeScript can infer it to be an array of strings. If it's ever interpreted as `any`, that's an indication that there's a problem.

Comment: `lines` comes from `rawtext.split(/n/)`.  How do I teach TypeScript that this will be an array of strings?

Comment: That will work if `rawtext` is a string - but it sounds like it isn't, perhaps it's `any`. Fix whatever's generating `rawtext` so that TS sees that it's a string.

Comment: `rawText` comes from `rawtext = blob.toString()`.  I guess I expected `toString()` to return a `string`.

Comment: Sounds like `blob` isn't typed properly either. If it's typed as a Blob, it works fine. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gIwk7AXPAEJ7YDcAUMuljFAO4YgAeWAvDmQHQZIDKGGAEsUAcwAUASio1M8CKJBp4nek1YZuaAA6KMEgOQAdFIZlA

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Thanks.  `blob` came from a function that didn't declare a return type.  Again, I guess I expected that whatever type `blob` has, `blob.toString()` would be guaranteed to return a `string`.  Oh, well!  I'll just roll with it!